How to set up classes for parsing custom data types in C#
I'm working on a saving/loading system, and I'm trying to serialize and deserialize various objects.  I'm working in Unity, and I've created one custom class for the game objects and their behaviours, another custom class to store the data for serialization, then a third class with methods to parse the data class into the object class.  The objects themselves are markers and the problem I'm running into is I want to create multiple Marker classes, each with slightly different data (for example, Text Markers, Image Markers, 3D Object Markers, etc.)
I'm trying to come up with a clean way of using inheritance to allow all marker types to inherit from a base Marker class, all marker data to inherit from a MarkerData class, and the marker parsers inherit from a MarkerParser class.  For example:
public class NodeParser : MonoBehaviour
{
    MarkerData markers;

    public void CreateMarkersFromJSON()
    {
        string json = ReadAllText("MarkerData.json");
        MarkerCollection<MarkerData> newMarkers = JsonUtility.FromJson<MarkerCollection<MarkerData>>(json);

        markers = new MarkerCollection<MarkerData>();

        for (int i = 0; i < newMarkers.markers.Count; i++)
        {
            CreateMarkerObject(newMarkers.markers[i]);
            markers.Add(new MarkerData(newMarkers.markers[i].pos));
        }   
    }

    public virtual void CreateMarkerObject(MarkerData data)
    {
        //Create marker GameObject based on MarkerData
    }
}

and
public class TextNodeParser : NodeParser
{
    TextMarkerData markers;

    public override void CreateMarkerObject(TextMarkerData data)
    {
        //Create marker GameObject based on TextMarkerData
    }

}

My thought was since TextMarkerData inherits from MarkerData, the CreateMarkersFromJSON() function would be able to parse any kind of MarkerData, then call the derived class's CreateMarkerObject() function to actually create the object.  The issue I'm running into is that the base class always just calls its own CreateMarkerObject() function, since the data is being parsed as MarkerData.  I thought about moving the parsing logic to the derived class, but then I'd have to rewrite it for each marker type and then it doesn't seem like there's much point in using inheritance.  I've also tried using generics, but then you're limited in terms of base class functionality (for example you can't create new instances of a generic type).
I feel like this must be a relatively common pattern but I can't find any good guides on how to implement it.  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Json.NET is now officially supported by unity, see here.  It has multiple different ways to support polymorphism, you might consider switching.

" the data is being parsed as MarkerData" You mean the data is serialized always as base one. Take look at the JSON file, do you see type indicators there? If not you have to handle serializing properly -- one approach is to add type indicators when serializing, if I remember correctly it adds meta members (in JSON file) "$type" : "GivenTypeName".

Need to use a generic type argument to specify the type to be parsed. Here is a minimal example:
public class NodeParser<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MarkerData
{
    public virtual void CreateMarkerObject(T data)
    {
        //Create marker GameObject based on MarkerData
    }
}

public class TextNodeParser : NodeParser<TextMarkerData>
{
    public override void CreateMarkerObject(TextMarkerData data)
    {
        //Create marker GameObject based on TextMarkerData
    }
}


Wow, I didn't know you could do that, I think that mostly solved what I need.  The only outstanding issue now is it seems like each Parser is now considered a different type, e.g. NodeParser, NodeParser, etc.  I would like to create a collection of all the parsers to iterate through them and thought that creating a list of NodeParser would work since all TextMarkerData etc. inherit from MarkerData, but it seems I need to refer to it as the derived class.  Is there any way around this?
